# HandlebarsJS not outputting html template unless receives a param

Tags: handlebars.js

I have this code:

```
if (this.template) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile( $(this.template).html() );
        $(this.el).html(template());
    }
```

with this template:

```
<script id="tmpl-nav-account" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#this}}
<div class="nav-account">
    topbar
</div>
{{/this}}
```

However, if run the 'template()' function with no params, nothing outputs. Yet, if I pass something in like: "template('ben')", it outputs the static HTML fine. Anyone got any ideas?

Does template() always have to have something passed into it to render the template?

EDIT:

If I remove the {{#this}} from the template, then it works with no parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` at the top level of a template is the argument you supply to the compiled template function. So, given this:

```
var o = { ... };
var t = Handlebars.compile(some_template_text);
t(o);
```

`this` will be `o` at the top level of the template. So, if you say `template()`, `this` is `undefined` inside the template and `{{#this}}` won't do anything because `undefined` is false in a boolean context.

You can see this clearly if you use this template:

```
<script id="tmpl-nav-account" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#this}}
        <div class="nav-account">
            {{this.where_is}}
        </div>
    {{/this}}
</script>​
```

and this JavaScript:

```
var t = Handlebars.compile($('#tmpl-nav-account').html());
console.log(t());
console.log(t({ where_is: 'pancakes house?' }));​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fS8c9/